# Emit to the two different state in one stream flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I want to emit to the two different state in one stream, but first emit didn't trigger, directly trigger the second emit.

I have tried hold it using Future.delayed, but it still doesn't work, bloc automatically pass the first emit and trigger the second emit (i know it when check it in debug mode)

```
on<AnEvent>((event, emit) async {
  emit(somethingState1());
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 5));
  emit(somethingState2());
}
```

My conclusions based on answers below:

1. Use emit.foreach. I don't know how to use it. It needs stream parameter, but where the stream?. If i must create first, how? i just know event, bloc, and state.
2. Use BlocListener. Both states is received, but if i use bloclistener, when receive state, the widget doesn't auto update. Auto update just works when use blocbuilder.
3. Maybe multiple emit working in flutter cubit, not in flutter bloc.

So, there isn't any method to emit 2 states in 1 stream. I use not efficient way, using 2 stream and 2 state. Trigger the first stream, after receive first state, then trigger second stream, and receive second state.

Comment: What is the middle operation you are trying to do that will trigger the next emit?

Comment: I don't trigger anything between first emit and second emit. Future delayed between them just make the interval. Bloc do emit very fast, so i put delay to give a time for first emit finished

Comment: then I think It is working as expected, if you need to emit different state, that  might have some logic.  Also emitter provides `.forEach` method that can be used to emit different state from stream

Comment: `BlocListener<FooBloc, String>( listener: (ctx, state) => print('state: $state'), child: ...`

Comment: @pskink when i use bloclistener, then do conditional if (state is stateA) {} else if (state is stateB) {}. it trigger both conditional

Comment: and how do you want to see those two different states if they are emitted in the same time?

Comment: @pskink that's why i use future delayed to create a queue, not emit the same time. but the bloc only trigger the second emit, i don't know why bloc pass the first emit.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding how the stream and bloc working.

- Imagine you have a pistol, the barrel is stream and each bullet is a state.
- You pull the trigger first time, you `emit(someState1)`.
- You pull the trigger second time, you `emit(someState2)`.
- The period between 2 actions above, is how your your bullet was impacted, explodes, and ejected out of barrel = **your business logic**. It could be `await Future.delayed()`, it could be `await http.callLoginRequest()`, it could be anything.

Action "pull the trigger", or `emit(someStateXX)` is JUST AN ACTION to tell your UI shows loading widget or success/fail dialog or anything.

Back to your question:

- `emit(somethingState1());`: Tell your UI shows loading widget.
- `await doSomething()`: Do some logic here, like you said: **"checked already send and arrive"**.
- `emit(somethingState2());`: After logic completed, tell UI to update success/fail dialog.

If you don't use `await Future.delayed()`, or `await doSomething()`, it just like you are using a machine gun. 2 bullets were injected out of barrel ***almost*** immediately makes us feel 2 bullets come through at the same time. In your Flutter, it may be happens in micro-seconds and cause to our misunderstanding.

Comment: Delay that you said just to make a distance between first bullet and second bullet. But what happened in here, i want to trigger 2 bullets, sequentially, but when ejected only second bullet that i see, first bullet disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The states update too fast and the app doesn't have time to listen to the first one because immediatelly the second one is triggerd. You can put even a smaller delay i think and it won't really affect the app, but will help you with what you want to achieve

Comment: That is what i do, use delay to give a time for first emit. But how much time that i need to delay it? microseconds? seconds?. It is relative. If my phone is very slow, how much the time for delay it? so i think it is not efficient

Comment: You can try to implement a different logic and try to limit to only one state per if case and do multiple things when you listen to it in blocconsumer builder in the page

Answer (score 0):

Emitter provides `.forEach` method that can be used to emit multiple state.  There will be some business logic in stream.

```dart
on<Add>((event, emit) async {
  Stream<int> stream = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i);//your stream
  await emit.forEach(
    stream,
    onData: (data) {
      // dont need to wrap with `emit`,onData expect State in return
      if(data.isEven) StateA();      
      else StateB();
    },//it also provides  onError
  );
});
```

Comment: 1) what stream i must input? i just know event, bloc, and state || 2) can you give more detail in "onData" please? what state i inputted there? and what is return do you mean?

Comment: `onData` is part of  [forEach](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/forEach.html) method.  Input depends on your business logic. And the way you are currently doing might suite but not clear  from your question. More about [Stream](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html)